# ARAMCO's financial statements

Tags: ipo, financial-statements

Can anybody explain me how come that ARAMCOS financial reports are available to the  public while its not publicly traded company.

Thank you!

Comment: Anyone can make their own stuff public.

Comment: ARAMCO had to produce financial statements ahead of it's $10 Billion public bond offering in April. There is _also_ speculation that they may go public, but that's was the initial impetus.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple.**

They are planning to perhaps make ARAMCO a publicly traded company.

In order to do that, it's practically impossible at the same time to hide the financial statements. People won't invest in a public company without knowing its financials.

So, even though ARAMCO is currently not a publicly traded company, someday it could be.